# iOS google gvr sdk.GVRAudioEngine Failed to set requested file properties: 1718449215

Tags: ios, audio, google-vr

when i use gvraudioSDK try to preload Ambisonic sound files Object,this failed message appear.

> GvrAudioEemo[10106:51434] 711: EXCEPTION (1718449215): "create audio >converter"
>   2018-01-30 10:17:54.661309+0800 GvrAudioEemo[10106:51434] Failed to set >requested file properties: 1718449215

It seem preload sound files failed.

my code:

```
//code:
self.gvrEngine = [[GVRAudioEngine alloc] initWithRenderingMode:kRenderingModeBinauralHighQuality];
BOOL preloadSuccess = [self.gvrEngine preloadSoundFile:kObjectSoundFile];    
BOOL startSuccess = [self.gvrEngine start];
// Generate seed for random number generation.
srand48(time(0));

// Spawn the first cube.
int soundId = [self.gvrEngine createSoundfield:kObjectSoundFile];

if (soundId != -1) {
    [self.gvrEngine setSoundObjectPosition:soundId x:4 y:0 z:0];
    [self.gvrEngine setSoundVolume:soundId volume:0.8];
}
[self.gvrEngine setHeadPosition:0 y:0 z:0];
[self.gvrEngine playSound:soundId loopingEnabled:true];
```

kObjectSoundFile is a file name of 4 channel audio file.I debug the code and found the 'preloadSuccess' is false.Can someone help me with this?